# On Elementor using Woocommerce, header doesn't show up on Shop and Product pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’ve built my website http://tsukidoki.art/ with Elementor and I’m using Woocommerce for my digital art products. One problem I’m encountering but can’t seem to fix is that the header disappears on the Shop (http://tsukidoki.art/shop/) and single product pages. It’s not even being called as the below header wrapper is nowhere to be seen in dev tools.

I’ve disabled all plugins and enabled them one by one and found out that Woocommerce and Elementor are conflicting with each other. They’re supposed to be compatible seeing as Woocommerce is the most popular choice for ecommerce on Wordpress, so I’m a bit dumbfounded as to why my problem seems so obscure. I couldn’t find anything when I tried troubleshooting and looking around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "with Elementor". Have you tried to get support for Elementor?